# R: combine rows with measurement below certain threshold

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a "toy" data frame with 2 columns (`x` and `y`) and 8 rows. I would like to merge and sum all rows where `y < 10`. Value of merged `x` is not very important.

```
x = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")
y = c(20,17,16,14,12,9,6,5)

df = data.frame(x,y)
df

    x   y
1   A   20
2   B   17
3   C   16
4   D   14
5   E   12
6   F   9
7   G   6
8   H   5
```

Desired output:

```
    x   y
1   A   20
2   B   17
3   C   16
4   D   14
5   E   12
6   F   20
```

`F` is not necessary and can be set to `Other`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
x = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")
y = c(20,17,16,14,12,9,6,5)

df = data.frame(x = x[which(y > 10)],y = y[which(y > 10)])
df = rbind(df,data.frame(x = 'f',y = sum(y[which(y < 10)])))
```

Comment: why not just `df = data.frame(x = c(x[y >= 10], "Other"), y = c(y[y >= 10], sum(y[y < 10])))` ? (you don't need the `which` there and I added the possibility of y being equal to 10 to avoid "orphans"...)

Answer (score 1):

We can also try with `subset/transform/rbind`

```
 rbind(subset( df, y>=10), 
      transform(subset(df, y<10), x= x[1], y= sum(y))[1,])
```